# Использование Wi-Fi в андроид-эмуляторе

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.
Можно ли использовать на эмуляторе андроида Wi-Fi.
Использовал аndroid studio. Написал следующую функцию. Она все время говорит, что wi-fi отключен.

```
public void onTurn(View view) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
        tv.setText("Проверка");
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiManager Wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        if(wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            tv.append("Wifi is enabled");
        }
        else
        {
            tv.append("Wifi is disabled");
        }

    }
```

В манифесте все разрешил.

```
<uses-permission android:name="ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: а что мешает на устройстве тестить?)

Comment: в 2016, как бы мне не было стыдно, я не имею смартфона(.

Answer (score 1):

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
//Создали одну переменную

WifiManager Wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
//Создали вторую

Wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
//Включили одну
   if(wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled())//Проверяем уже почему-то другую
        {
            tv.append("Wifi is enabled");
        }
        else
        {
            tv.append("Wifi is disabled");
        }
```

У меня, кстати, эмуль постоянно включенный wi-fi показывает=)

Comment: Блин совсем слепой на старости лет стал. Ну да, теперь постоянно включен показывает.  Однако все же интересно, как работает вай-фай эмулятора? Он является вай-фаем компьютера, на котором нах-ся? Может ли виртуальная машина подключаться к другим устройствам?

Comment: Если честно, это я пока сам незнаю)